# CustomProperties are not saved in recurring meeting in Outlook add-in using Office.js

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office365-apps

We are adding a custom property using

```
  customProps.set("otherProp", "value");
  customProps.saveAsync(saveCallback);
```

As mentioned in the documentation, this works fine in a normal meeting but when we do the same in a recurring meeting, the properties are not stored in exchange. Next time if we open the meeting again the custom properties are not found. Is there any work around to save custom property to a recurring meeting instance.

Answer (score 0):

API support between Mac/Windows Outlook different.
Can you mention the outlook version and OS  you are seeing problems with ?

Comment: Outlook 2016, with windows 10.